# Can't parseInt the value of prompt

Tags: javascript

I am triying to rest the values i get from prompts to get the results but i've tried several combinations and I always get Nan
you already catched

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mis Pokemons</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
var kanto = 151
var johto = 100
var hoenn = 135
var sinnoh = 107
var totalPokemons = kanto + johto + hoenn + sinnoh
var teFaltanDeKanto = kanto - cuantosKanto
var teFaltandeJohto = johto - cuantosJohto

var cuantosKanto = prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Kanto?');
        cuantosKanto = parseInt(cuantosKanto);


var cuantosJohto = parseInt(prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Johto?'));

var cuantosHoenn = prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Hoenn?');

var cuantosSinnoh = prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Sinnoh?');

document.write('Has capturado ' + cuantosKanto + ' pokemons de Kanto y te faltan ' + teFaltanDeKanto + 'Has capturado ' + cuantosJohto + ' de johto y te faltan ' + teFaltandeJohto);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use variables before defining them.

This is one of your major issues in your code, you are subtracting the value of `cuantosKanto` from `kanto` when `cuantosKanto` is not defined and neither have a value yet.

Here is the issue:

```
var teFaltanDeKanto = kanto - cuantosKanto
var teFaltandeJohto = johto - cuantosJohto
```

So, what I'd recommend is that you do your calc inline like this:

```
`Región Kanto: ${cuantosKanto} capturados. ${Pokemons.kanto-cuantosKanto} restantes.`
```

And as you may have seen, I am using the object `Pokemons`. This will help you keep your code readable so you can understand it a lot better:

```
const Pokemons = {
  "kanto":151,
  "johto":100,
  "hoenn":135,
  "sinnoh":107,
  "total":function(){
    return this.kanto+this.johto+this.hoenn+this.sinnoh
   }
};
```

This way you can access the total Pokémons in any region by doing `Pokemons.sinnoh`. And even get the total Pokémons by doing `Pokemons.total()`.

### NOTE

> The recommended method to parse a string into a number for this case is to use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

This means instead of doing:

```
var cuantosKanto = parseInt(prompt("Number"));
```

You can just do:

```
var cuantosKanto = +prompt("Number");
```

With everything said and detailed, here is an example of everything mentioned:

#### CODE:

```js
const Pokemons = {
  "kanto":151,
  "johto":100,
  "hoenn":135,
  "sinnoh":107,
  "total":function(){
    return this.kanto+this.johto+this.hoenn+this.sinnoh
   }
};

var cuantosKanto = +prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Kanto?');

var cuantosJohto = +prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Johto?');

var cuantosHoenn = +prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Hoenn?');

var cuantosSinnoh = +prompt('¿Cuantos pokemon has capturado de la región de Sinnoh?');

var capturados = cuantosKanto+cuantosJohto+cuantosHoenn+cuantosSinnoh;

document.write(`
  Has capturado ${capturados} pokémon de ${Pokemons.total()}.<br><br>
  
  Región Kanto: ${cuantosKanto} capturados.<br>
  ${Pokemons.kanto-cuantosKanto} restantes.<br><br>
  
  Region Johto: ${cuantosJohto} capturados.<br>
  ${Pokemons.johto-cuantosJohto} restantes.<br><br>
  
  Region Hoenn: ${cuantosHoenn} capturados.<br>
  ${Pokemons.hoenn-cuantosHoenn} restantes.<br><br>
  
  Region Sinnoh: ${cuantosSinnoh} capturados.<br>
  ${Pokemons.sinnoh-cuantosSinnoh} restantes.<br><br> 
`);
```

Comment: Thank you. Just starting and my head explodes!

Answer (score -1):

These two statements don't do what you expecct:

```
var teFaltanDeKanto = kanto - cuantosKanto
var teFaltandeJohto = johto - cuantosJohto
```

You are attempting to add two numbers together, but `cuantosKanto` and `cuantosJohto` have not been assigned a value at that point.

So move those two statements to just above the `document.write()` statement.